# Trouble chrome remote desktop install

Tags: chrome-remote-desktop

I try to install Chrome remote desktop on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. After the installation procedure via ssh configuration.
After that I can't see the computer on the acces webpage.

Here is the log journal:

```
août 01 16:26:48 expc2-XPS-8960 systemd[3944]: pam_unix(chrome-remote-desktop:session): session closed for user expc2
août 01 16:26:48 expc2-XPS-8960 systemd[1]: chrome-remote-desktop@expc2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
août 01 16:26:48 expc2-XPS-8960 systemd[1]: chrome-remote-desktop@expc2.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
août 01 16:26:48 expc2-XPS-8960 chrome-remote-desktop[3943]:   File "/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop", line 1013, in setup_audio
août 01 16:26:48 expc2-XPS-8960 chrome-remote-desktop[3943]:   File "/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop", line 2576, in main
août 01 16:26:48 expc2-XPS-8960 chrome-remote-desktop[3943]:   File "/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop", line 2600, in <module>
août 01 16:26:48 expc2-XPS-8960 systemd[3943]: pam_unix(chrome-remote-desktop:session): session opened for user expc2 by (uid=0)
août 01 16:26:48 expc2-XPS-8960 sudo[3916]: expc2 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/expc2 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl enable --now chrome-remote-desktop@expc2
août 01 16:10:03 expc2-XPS-8960 sudo[3563]: expc2 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/expc2 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop@expc2.service
août 01 16:09:37 expc2-XPS-8960 sudo[3449]: expc2 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/usr/lib/systemd/system ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop.service
août 01 16:09:32 expc2-XPS-8960 sudo[3445]: expc2 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/usr/lib/systemd/system ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl start chrome-remote-desktop.service
août 01 16:08:43 expc2-XPS-8960 sudo[3222]: expc2 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/usr/lib/systemd/system ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl enable chrome-remote-desktop@
août 01 16:05:34 expc2-XPS-8960 sudo[3182]: expc2 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/usr/lib/systemd/system ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop@expc2.service
août 01 16:04:17 expc2-XPS-8960 sudo[3135]: expc2 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/usr/lib/systemd/system ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop@botond.service
août 01 16:03:49 expc2-XPS-8960 sudo[3125]: expc2 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/usr/lib/systemd/system ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop.service
août 01 16:03:43 expc2-XPS-8960 polkitd(authority=local)[867]: Operator of unix-session:3 successfully authenticated as unix-user:expc2 to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action org.f>
août 01 16:03:26 expc2-XPS-8960 polkitd(authority=local)[867]: Operator of unix-session:3 successfully authenticated as unix-user:expc2 to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action org.f>
lines 1-23
```

I try to follow many post to fix the error but nothing works. Mainly I try that procedure :
[https://en.linuxportal.info/tutorials/troubleshooting/how-can-we-manually-unmask-servi[…]nnot-unmask-with-the-unmask-option-of-the-systemctl-command](https://en.linuxportal.info/tutorials/troubleshooting/how-can-we-manually-unmask-servi%5B%E2%80%A6%5Dnnot-unmask-with-the-unmask-option-of-the-systemctl-command)

I also try to execute manuation that command:** /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop --start --new-session**

I get that error:

```
2023-08-01 16:45:08,461:WARNING:WARNING: This system uses GDM. Some GDM versions have a bug that prevents local login while Chrome Remote Desktop is running. If you run into this issue, you can stop Chrome Remote Desktop by visiting https://remotedesktop.google.com/access on another machine and clicking the delete icon next to this machine. It may take up to five minutes for the Chrome Remote Desktop to exit on this machine and for local login to start working again.
2023-08-01 16:45:08,462:INFO:Using host_id: ***********
2023-08-01 16:45:08,476:INFO:xserver-xorg-video-dummy is not up-to-date
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop", line 2600, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop", line 2576, in main
    desktop.setup_audio(host.host_id, backoff_time)
  File "/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop", line 1013, in setup_audio
    xdg.BaseDirectory.get_runtime_dir(strict=False), runtime_dirname)
AttributeError: module 'xdg' has no attribute 'BaseDirectory'
2023-08-01 16:45:08,525:INFO:Cleanup.
```

It seems there is a problem with xdg

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I solved it by changing /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop as follows

Adding `from xdg import BaseDirectory` and renaming `xdg.BaseDirectory` to `BaseDirectory` works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can also rollback to the prevoious version (115) meanwhile they're fixing it. For example this mirror still has it: [chrome-remote-desktop_115.0.5790.10_amd64.deb](https://deb.rug.nl/ppa/mirror/dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb/pool/main/c/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop_115.0.5790.10_amd64.deb)